# Wordpress Dashboard Login Internal 500 Error

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, internal-server-error

The company I work for is currently using WordPress platform for their website.  Since I have been with this company for a year there have been a lot of Internal 500 errors with the website.  The most recent error will not allow me to log into the Dashboard of my website.

For example if I navigate to www.mysite.com/wp-admin/  and try to log in.  It will redirect me to an error page with this syntax

> " HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. "

I have contacted the hosting company and they said everything is correct on their end.  Since i did not develop this site I'm not sure what the previous developer did to possibly have these errors show up. Previously Ive fixed this problem by changing / removing the .htaccess but in this case it has not been working for me.   My last option would be to reinstall WordPress / design on a new platform fresh but before that any suggestions would help!

Comment: what changes done in htaccess

Comment: no real specific changes.  I have just been renaming the .htaccess file.   That has been temporarily fixing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of the plugins is causing the error after you login. If you can access the file through FTP you should try going to wp-content/plugins/ and remove all the plugins from there (just copy and paste to somewhere else). Then try to login.

If that works, than you can start adding the plugins back one at a time, and see which one is causing the errors.

If the website relies heavily on plugins, know that some functionality will be lost during that time.

Comment: Yes,  The full website is functioning perfectly fine but I have completely no access to the backend of the website